# Access Event ID in a AWS RDS Event subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html#USER_Events.Messages), when creating a *RDS Event subscription* you can select any number *Event categories* that will produce specific *Event messages*.

Then you can choose to send a notification to an *E-mail*, *SMS* or, which is my case, to a *SNS topic* that triggers a Lambda execution.

How to access the *RDS Event ID* - i.e. `RDS-EVENT-0006` - from the Lambda `event` parameter?

Comment: I recommend putting a `print(event)` statement in the Lambda function. Then, trigger the function from RDS. This will result in the event being dumped to CloudWatch Logs (if you have permissions setup correctly). Then you'll be able to see the fields being provided and you can parse out the Event ID.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, do you know if is there any way of mocking the event trigger?

Comment: The AWS Lambda console has a Test capability where you can provide the event message. This way, you can test the Lambda function without having to use the Trigger, but the function behaves the same.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Precisely, what I am trying to figure out is what the topology of that event message is...

Comment: The best way is to trigger such a message and capture it in the logs.

Answer (score 2):

Add a trigger event like this cloudformation example :

DbRestoredEventRule:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    Name: "xyz-db-restored"
    Description: "xyz restored"
    EventPattern:
      source:
        - "aws.rds"
      detail-type:
        - "RDS DB Instance Event"
      detail:
        EventCategories:
          - "availability"
      Message:
        - 'DB instance restarted'
    Targets:
      - Arn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - "MigrationDataFunction"
            - "Arn"
        Id: "TargetFunctionV1"